# database padding space if the value inserted has smaller length than column size- DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I was checking if DB pads spaces in a column if the inserted string has fewer characters than the designated length of the column. Example:

lets say size of `<column1>` is **10** but the value entered is **abc** - then is it `abc_______` which the DB stores where `_` represents spaces?

I am asking because I used `LTRIM-RTRIM` while **INSERT**ing the values and on again fetching the value in the very next minute I got the result as  `abc_______`.

Comment: why all the tags? Which DB are you using?

Comment: Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @data_henrik Done

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done

Comment: It's the standard for CHAR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [`CHAR` or `CHARACTER` datatype](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/intro/src/tpc/db2z_stringdatatypes.html) for the column. The `CHAR` or `CHARACTER` datatype is a fixed length datatype and is padded with space at the end of the value to fill the column size.

You can use `VARCHAR` to avoid the padding with spaces at the end of the values.

**Note:** Make sure you are using `CHARACTER_LENGTH` on `CHARACTER` columns to get the correct character length (without padding spaces). The result of `LENGTH` also includes the padding spaces.

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=322cc38217bde8daea3671b823f00e7d)

Comment: Does it create trouble when in where clause when I use a variable of greater length against a column but know to me that the value in that variable won't be greater than that column's size?

Comment: You are right about `char` being used instead of  `varchar`

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus should not be a problem.